# Can I try Amazon EC2 for free?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Will I be charged for Amazon EC2 if I have very low traffic and usage ?

ok It's not that expensive except I work for Big Corporate it's difficult to have a credit card so I have to use mine and I don't want to risk that my card would be blown out.

Second they say for traffice below 1 Go it's free. So is there some catch ?

Comment: Have you considered asking Amazon? We are not their support department.

Comment: Why my question at http://serverfault.com/questions/422762/how-many-free-instance-we-can-have-in-amazon-ec2-anyway is downvoted so much and this one is okay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After November the 1st, you can sign up for the [Free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/):

> Beginning November 1, new AWS customers will be able to run a free Amazon EC2 Micro Instance for a year, while also leveraging a new free usage tier for Amazon S3, Amazon Elastic Block Store, Amazon Elastic Load Balancing, and AWS data transfer. AWS’s free usage tier can be used for anything you want to run in the cloud: launch new applications, test existing applications in the cloud, or simply gain hands-on experience with AWS.

Comment: Came in here to suggest that... Can't wait for Nov 1st to try it out.

Comment: I think you mean "After November 1", not "Until..."

Comment: @Kristopher: You can sign up _until_ November the 1st and start running _after_. Which reminds me...

Answer (score 9):

Amazon EC2 is a server rental. The rental fee is by hour of rental, you also have to pay for the bandwidth your server uses.
See their [pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Given the pricing structure of Amazon's EC2 it doesn't cost much to fire up a small (m1.small) instance and bang around on it for a couple of hours and shut it back down and still not cost you more than a few dollars. With a small instance running $0.10/hour it's not that expensive to give it a trial run. You'd have to do a lot of storage and lot of bandwidth to get those to get high within a couple hours as well.

Comment: It's not that expensive except I work for Big Corporate it's difficult to have a credit card so I have to use mine and I don't want to risk that my card would be blown out.

Answer (score 2):

If this implementation is for testing out cloud computing, you may want to check out Eucalyptus Community Cloud @ http://open.eucalyptus.com/CommunityCloud 
There you can testdrive and experiment with Eucalyptus, a software framework for cloud computing using a framework that is based on the Amazon EC2 API.

Comment: I suspect the cost (in both effort and resources) in setting up even a small test Eucalyptus system would exceed the cost of running a couple of VMs in EC2 for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 (and the other Amazon cloud services) have no free plans afaik.

Google app engine does, but it is of course a different sort of service.

Comment: They say it's free for less than 1 Go so my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can.

The first year is free under the free user tier for new registered users. The transfer amount is 10GB in and 10GB out. I am using it.

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a hard look at Skytap (www.skytap.com). They have a free 30 day trial running right now and I have heard plenty of good things about them recently.

Comment: 30 day trials is not interesting: I don't have time to really develop a small app to really test it. Also there's no price announced.

Comment: I don't think the price range is what the submitter is asking for - Skytap has a simple, low cost subscription model starting at $500/month .